# SQL Server session queries

Tags: performance, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-queue

To be able to access a session query all the results that I found during my research is about the last query executed in a SQL Server session.

Is there a way to access all the queries that has run inside session instead of SQL Server profiler because to use profiler in prduction environment is not that easy.

Any helps?

Answer (score 0):

I possibly found [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/01/sql-server-get-query-running-in-session/) a solution to your problem. I added a cursor to get all queries for a specific session:

```
DECLARE @sql TABLE(sql_handle VARBINARY(128))
DECLARE @sqltext VARBINARY(128)

INSERT INTO @sql
SELECT sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses p
WHERE p.spid = (YOUR_SESSION_ID)

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT sql_handle 
FROM @sql
OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
INTO @sqltext
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT TEXT
        FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)
        FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @sqltext
    END
CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor;
GO
```

I hope this is what you are searching for.

Comment: sorry but this is also about the last executed query of a session, I am looking for all the queries in a specific session

Comment: actually you are partially right because when I query group by by spid and with count it gives me more than 1 count for spid ID but when I directly search for it, it returns 1 result